# how to get value of dynamic input field in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating 3 send enquiry buttons dynamically with 3 hidden fields with different values. When I click the send enquiry button I get same values of hidden fields all the time instead of different value. here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function f1()
            {
                var val1 = document.getElementById('para1');
                var val2 = document.getElementById('really').value;
                val1.innerHTML = val2;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        mysql_select_db('advertising site');
        $selectquery = "select * from business_ads";
        $result = mysql_query($selectquery) or die(mysql_error());
        $resultrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $companyname = $row['company_name']; ?>
            <p id="company_name" name="company_name"><?php echo $companyname ?></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_company_name" value="<?php echo $companyname ?>"id="really"> 
            <input type="button" name="send_enquiry" id="send_enquiry" value="Send Enquiry" onclick="f1();">
        <?php } ?>
        <p id="para1"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: all 3 hidden inputs have the same name. they must have different names.

Comment: when the name are different how can i get the values

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

without changing your current code, you can access the elements via javascript using the `getElementsByName` function which will return an array containing the elements with the same name. (If you gave them unique id's you could find them by `getElementById` which would be slightly faster and backwards compatible with older browsers-- every ID on a page is supposed to be unique so you can't use it to select multiple elements with the same ID)

usage:

```
var companyarray = document.getElementsByName('hidden_company_name');
companyarray.forEach(function(element) {
    //do something with each element
    alert(element.value);
});
```

Comment: sorry but i am getting the respective hidden field value and display it on the screen without any form

Comment: how can i get the value with javascript because php needs form to get and display content of hidden field

Comment: anybody know this answer

Comment: but how can i know which send_query button was pressed so that it show me there respective hidden field

Comment: please check indiamart.com and click on send enquiry button and then you will see a modal box in that modal box there is a company name and i want exactly like that how to display that company name when all the data is coming from database